# FosUserBundle override template resetting

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

What can will be, for password resetting override templating, for login all works okey, identicaly for resetting no.

```
    class CmsBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOSUserBundle';
    }
}
```

// CmsBundle/Resources/view/FOSUserBundle/Resetting/request.html.twig

```
{% extends "@Cms/base.html.twig" %}

{% block fos_user_content %}
    {{ include('@Cms/FOSUserBundle/views/Resetting/request_content.html.twig') }}
{% endblock fos_user_content %}
```

// request content

```
    {% block fos_user_content %}

    <form action="{{ path('fos_user_resetting_send_email') }}" method="POST" class="fos_user_resetting_request">
        <div>
            <label for="username">{{ 'Resetting.request.username'|trans }}</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required="required" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="{{ 'Resetting.request.submit'|trans }}" />
        </div>
    </form>

{% endblock fos_user_content %}
```

Comment: know and for login don't work

Answer (score 0):

The `getParent()` / `return 'FOSUserBundle';` extension may not be required if you put the files into the app/ directory: `app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/Resetting/request.html.twig`.

Also, the Resetting/reset_content.html.twig should just be plain HTML, not in  `{% block ... %}`.